# Javascript: Opening windows in a row problem

Tags: javascript, firefox

this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Something</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Try Me!</a>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$("a").click(function(event){
  for(id=0;id<=10;id++){
    setTimeout(function() {
      var local_id = id;
      window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID="+local_id,"", "win"+local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
      }, 3000*id);
   }
   event.preventDefault();
});

   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This link is opening each window 3 seconds after the next.

This is the row I need: `http://www.mysite.com/characterID=1, http://www.mysite.com/characterID=2, http://www.mysite.com/characterID=3...`

But it always opens `http://www.mysite.com/characterID=11`

How can I fix it?

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue.

You're overwriting `local_id` in the loop, and always referring to the same variable when the code runs. This is because JavaScript *does not have block scope*, just function scope.

So to scope the `id`, you need to invoke a function, and define the variable (or function parameter) there.

```
function createWindow(local_id) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID=" + local_id, "", "win" + local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
    }, 3000 * local_id);
}

for (id = 0; id <= 10; id++) {
    createWindow(id);
}
```

---

Or a similar patter would be to have the function return a function to the loop.

```
function createWindow(local_id) {
    return function() {
        window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID=" + local_id, "", "win" + local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
    };
}

for (id = 0; id <= 10; id++) {
    setTimeout( createWindow(id) , 3000 * id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `var local_id = id;` is called after the loop exits when id is set to 11.

Try this:

```
for(id=0;id<=10;id++){
   setTimeout('window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID='+id+'","win'+id+'","width=100,height=100,resizable")', 3000*id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic JavaScript closure issue.  The anonymous function is using the value `id` which is set to 11 at the end of the loop.  To fix this, you need to make a function that returns a function (that will close around the `id` value).

Try it like so:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    var timeout = function(local_id){
        return function(){
            window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID=" + local_id, "", "win" + local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
        };
    };
    for (id = 0; id <= 10; id++) {
        setTimeout(timeout(id), 3000 * id);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id as an additional parameter to setTimeout, like so: (This is essentially @mrk's answer with less evil.)

```
setTimeout(function(local_id) {
  window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID="+local_id,"", "win"+local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
  }, 3000*id, id);
```

Comment: Gah, that's what comes of not having some of the less cool browsers at hand to test :/

Answer (score 0):

After lots of years I wanted to answer my own question. I couldnt remember what I was trying to do but my solution should using `let` not `var`. `let` is scope bounded while var is not.

```
for(id=0;id<=10;id++){
    let local_id = id;    
    setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(local_id)
    }, 3000);
}
```